# How can I do a dynamic condition inside module?

Tags: terraform

Using Terraform, I am under the impression from trying and reading documentation that `dynamic` is not compatible with `module`. If that is the case, how could I do this dynamic condition where I will not include a aws `layer` directive if `var.enable_new_relic` is false?

```
module "lambda" {
  source = "git@github.com:foobar"

  for_each = local.lambda_configs

  function_name                  = "${local.name}-${each.key}"
  description                    = "foo-builder ${var.name} ${each.key}"
  runtime                        = each.value.runtime
  handler                        = var.enable_new_relic ? local.NEW_RELIC_LAYER_HANDLER : each.value.handler

  ...

  dynamic "new_relic" {
    for_each = var.enable_new_relic ? [1]: []
    content {
      layers = var.new_relic_lambda_layers
    }
  }
```

Comment: That logic would need to be inside the module itself.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks of type `dynamic` are only for generating nested blocks, and there aren't any nested blocks expected inside a `module` block so `dynamic` blocks are not valid there either.

If `new_relic` is a variable you've declared inside the module using a `variable "new_relic"` block then you can conditionally assign a value to that variable using [a conditional expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html):

```
module "lambda" {
  source   = "git@github.com:foobar"
  for_each = local.lambda_configs
  
  # ...
  new_relic = var.enable_new_relic ? {
    layers = var.new_relic_lambda_layers
  } : null
}
```

This either assigns an object value or a `null` value to the `new_relic` variable, depending on the value of `var.enable_new_relic`. This is a conditional version of the following equivalent that you might write if you wanted to *always* set that variable:

```
  new_relic = {
    layers = var.new_relic_lambda_layers
  }
```